# Can you always have a vscode-server running?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, openssh, vscode-liveshare

I'm trying to use remote ssh and liveshare so I can have liveshare constantly running on a server, meaning anyone can collaborate at anytime. However, whenever I close the window I started the server on, the liveshare disconnects. Is there a way to have it running 24/7 on my server?

EDIT: I'm using Remote Development